# Use union type with wrapped object check

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use union types with simple primitives and some custom objects.  As an example, I took the sample union type demonstrated in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) in the Union Types section and added a contrived PaddingLeft type like so:

```
type PaddingLeft = {
  aNumber: string,
}

function padLeft(value: string, padding: string | number | PaddingLeft) {
  if (typeof padding === "object") {
    return padding.aNumber + value;
  }
  if (typeof padding === "number") {
    return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
  }
  if (typeof padding === "string") {
      return padding + value;
  }
  throw new Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
padLeft('1', 1);
padLeft('1', '2');
padLeft('1', {aNumber: '34'});
```

based on the implementation of padLeft above, Typescript is happy.  However, I'd really like to not write:

```
if (typeof padding === "object") {
```

but instead wrap the check of whether the supplied argument is an object inside a function so I can do additional checks beyond the simple typeof check.  As a start, I tried to write a function that just does the same thing as the typeof check, but inside a function:

```
function isObjectCheck (args: any) {
  return (typeof args === 'object');
}
```

and then I tried to replace the typeof check with the call to isObjectCheck (replacing the first line of the padLeft function):

```
if (isObjectCheck(padding)) {
```

Doing so causes Typescript to say:

> Property 'aNumber' does not exist on type 'string | number | PaddingLeft'.
>     Property 'aNumber' does not exist on type 'string'.

on the second line of the padLeft function.

How can I wrap the object check in a function, and also satisfy Typescript's checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for custom type guards. This will work:

```
type PaddingLeft = {
    aNumber: string,
}

function isObjectCheck(args: any): args is object {
    return (typeof args === 'object');
}

function padLeft(value: string, padding: string | number | PaddingLeft) {
    if (isObjectCheck(padding)) {
        return padding.aNumber + value;
    }
    if (typeof padding === "number") {
        return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
    }
    if (typeof padding === "string") {
        return padding + value;
    }
    throw new Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you.  It seems I should've scrolled further down in the documentation :)